# Increasing Maximum Web Service Requests in Oracle APEX 19.2

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to increase the maximum web service requests for my application in Oracle APEX earlier version of APEX 18.2 has an option to this in manage workspace section. But now this option is not found in APEX 19.2. Any idea how to achieve this?[APEX 18.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sExBR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the UI has moved or stripped out, but you should be able to set it via the APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.SET_PARAMETER procedure.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/SET_PARAMETER-Procedure.html#GUID-A6D8CA93-798D-4582-97B9-C7D3ED709AC5

The setting is MAX_WEBSERVICE_REQUESTS, which is in this list:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/Available-Parameter-Values.html#GUID-75DCF658-5A76-4E81-B12D-04E254A3D80A

As stated in the doc:

> APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN can be executed by the SYS or SYSTEM database
>   users and any database user granted the role APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE.